# New confirmation alert popup doesn't show on Windows

Tags: java, javafx

I'm able to open a new Alert Confirmation window when I click on a button in a JavaFX app on Ubuntu, but on Windows it won't show.

Is there any way I can find out why it won't show in Windows?

```
 @FXML private void newWindow(ActionEvent event) thros InterruptedException 
 {
 Alert a = new Alert(AlertType.Confirmation);

 ButtonType buttonTypeOk = new ButtonType("Yes", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
 ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("No",ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
 a.setTitle("....");
 *//a.initOwner(stage);* added
 a.setHeaderText("Warning!");
 a.setContentText("Do you accept?");

 Optional<ButtonType> result = a.showAndWait();
 if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK)
 {
  System.out.println("OK");
 } else
 {
  System.out.println("NO");
 }
}
```

I've added a.initOwner(stage); to the main class and just try to open it immediatly on "start", but on windows it now just opens and closes.

Still haven't found why it doesn't work, it is on Windows server 2012.

Comment: Can you provide some code, because without some sort of an indication on what you're doing there is no way we can help you.

Comment: Did you remember to pass your main Stage to the Alert’s [initOwner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#initOwner-javafx.stage.Window-) method before showing the Alert?

Comment: I did everything correct now right?